# Who taught Michael Myers how to drive?

Tags: plot-explanation, halloween

Myers escapes from prison and drives away. Later in the movie, his Doctor has this conversation

> WYNN: Sam, Haddonfield is a hundred and fifty miles from here. How could
>   he get there, he can't drive?
>
> LOOMIS: He was doing all right last night. Maybe somebody around here gave him lessons.

But who? Is there any logical explanation for him to know how to drive? Or can we just attribute it to his [supernatural](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82223/how-is-michael-myers-bulletproof)-ish presence?

Comment: In honor of Halloween's 40th birthday!

Comment: He watched a YouTube video? ;-)

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 No YouTube in 78!

Comment: [Halloween RARE Deleted Scene 1978 - Driving Lesson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=35&v=-c8jJRekwbA)

Comment: @AnkitSharma, that was most excellent!!!

Comment: Too much critical thinking.  Michael Myers is supernatural.  Once you accept that, reasons are not necessary.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger You could actually turn that into an answer by supporting scenes from Halloween Kills, where Myers is in-universe acknowledged as a force of evil, who cannot be stopped.

Comment: @BlueMoon93 I have litrally not watched any Halloween movies.  But I know some stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no other in-universe explanation other than the one given.  It's possible that one of the doctors, in an effort to spur learning and behavior, offered driving lessons as rewards for Myers.  Driving really isn't rocket science, even if that wasn't the case, I'm sure he was able to figure it out pretty quickly on his own.

But, in terms of "Who gave him lessons and how did he learn?", there is no canonical answer to that question outside Loomis' statement.

Comment: I also forget that the US doesn't often use manual gears like my country